# SQL Server Linux(Ubuntu) Connection Options

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, connection-string

In general SQL Server Connection Protocols allows three different connection protocols:

> 1. TCP/IP
> 2. Named Pipes
> 3. Shared Memory

in linux by default installation we can connect to the SQL Server using TCP/IP, the question is **is there any options for named pipes or shared memory or UNIX sockets?**

Also, it seems there is no option to enable or disable such features in Linux.

TCP/IP:

```
sqlcmd –S tcp:ServerName –U sa –P
```

Named Pipes:

```
sqlcmd –S np:\\ServerName\pipe\sql\query –U sa –P
```

Shared Memory:

```
sqlcmd –S lpc:ServerName –U sa –P
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/shared-memory-properties?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/named-pipes-properties?view=sql-server-ver15) protocols are only available with SQL Server on Windows.

Note the documentation links above call out "SQL Server (Windows only)" in the APPLIES TO header.

Comment: based on your links and the output of  /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf list that has no option about named pipes and shared memory, it seems that you are right